# Philippines - United States

Tags: united-states

Just wanna ask is there a way to file a case to a person even though we are here in the Philippines?

Our CEO from the US put a business here and then after 3 weeks of hiring us, they shut down the business without prior notification.

Now we keep on emailing them to have our pay but they keep on ignoring us.

please help.

Comment: Are there signed contracts? Hire a lawyer and sue them.

Comment: Was it a US business that put an office in the Philippines? Or a Filipino business that was founded/run/funded by an American?

Answer (score 4):

You can either sue the company in the US, or in the Philippines. It would be easier for you to sue in the Philippines, but easier to collect if the trial is in the US. You need to hire a lawyer and provide more details. In both countries, it is illegal to refuse to pay an employee for work done, but it is not clear from your description that you were legally employees (this could be a breech of contract case). The Fair Labor Standards Act (which requires employees to be paid) may be applicable to the company: although there is a ["foreign exemption"](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=80b0672201c0c12ce9322f7aaa7b35da&mc=true&node=pt5.1.551&rgn=div5) for word done overseas, this seems to relate to minimum wage, overtime and child labor, and not the basic obligation to pay wages.